# C#: Formatação de números (com ponto)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estou a trabalhar em `ASP.NET Core MVC` e `C#`.

Precisava de apresentar o número, p.ex., (double) 1000, como 1.000, quando presentemente o número é apresentado como 1000 .

A propriedade no modelo está como:

```
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,###}")]
        public double? Kms_Contrato { get; set; }
```

(parece que a formatação `{0:#,###}` não funciona...)

Nas views a propriedade é escrita como:

```
        @model MyType

        <td>@Model.Kms_Contrato</td>
```

e

```
      @model MyType

      Html.EditorFor(m => m.Kms_Contrato)
```

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1):

```
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.000}")]
    public double? Kms_Contrato { get; set; }
```

Comment: Esta solução não funciona!!!! (double) 90000é apresentado como 90000!!!